# Rails directory for saving users uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's more a curiosity question.

Right now I do `store_dir 'uploader_type/model.id` (for example: `profile_picture/1/`).

But I really want to know what is the best practice to name directories to store users uploaded files?

Answer (score 0):

Believe me, from my experience creating a directory structure will create more trouble than bring benefits. Folders tightly couple the file to the directory, which ultimately will make you life much more difficult to find a given file. Also, if one day you need to migrate the folders (specially in S3) you will need to create a script for that, as this is not a trivial task

Why not keeping all users uploaded pictures to
store_dir 'uploads/images'?

Than if you need to create a unique name you can for example

- **1. Create a MD5 of the image i.e [md5_hash].jpg**
- **2. Transport the "directory structure to the file" (im assuming you are using ruby -> "#{model.id}-#{model.class.to_s.downcase}.jpg"**

Assuming you have a `Profile` model and a `Car` model
you would end up with the following structure inside `uploads/images`

- 1_profile.jpg
- 2_profile.jpg
- 1_car.jpg
- 2_car.jpg